# Make default choice of user in windows 7 login to password type screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, login

I want to choose a default user in windows login screen so that it will get me straight to the password type screen.
I have tried this solution:

1. Enable Auto Logon: `reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1`
2. Set username for logon: `reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d youruser` from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/514265/set-user-for-auto-logon-on-windows-via-batch-script).

but the problem is it needs default password which I do not want to provide, so I can make the choice automatically but then it tries to type the password (I guess blank password) and i get wrong password notification.
I want to get to the password type screen automatically without choosing the user.

I'm using Windows 7 Pro x64.

Clarification:
When windows starts I have 2 users on my computers, normally i select my user then type the password and enter windows.
My wish is on windows start windows will automatically choose my user and all I have to do is type the password.
The solution I tried indeed choose my user but it also requires a default password to be provided so windows can enter the default password, but I do not want windows to enter the password for me, but only select my user and wait for me to type the password.

Comment: Doesn't windows 7 remember the last user who logged in? On my Win7-64 machine, I hit Ctrl-alt-del and my user name is selected, I type my password.  Can you give us more details about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Could you clarify 'but then it tries to type the password'.  Who or what is 'it'?  Also 'I want to get to the password type screen automatically without choosing the user'.  Then I would use the DefaultPassowrd setting in the registry.  (I note you dislike this solution).

Comment: Added clarification

Comment: You only need the AutoAdminLogon value if you want the computer to automatically log on. Sounds like you don't want that in this case, so you can delete that value from the registry and avoid setting it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Set the AutoAdminLogon Key to 0 and it should work:

`reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0`

There are 4 values associated with Auto Logons:

- AutoAdminLogon (0 or 1) will attempt (or not) to logon using the default stroed username, password and domain.  If set to 0, the credentials will still populate but the "Logon" button will not be auto-clicked (to simplify things)
- DefaultUserName is the registry value for the username field
- DefaultPassword is the value used to store the password field
- DefaultDomainName is the domain name being logged onto (for domain computers)