# Loading Windows 7 without selecting an account

Tags: windows-7

I have an Administrator account and a Standard account. Each time I start Windows, my computer pauses to ask which account I want to load. Is there a boot manager I can install that will automatically select the Administrator account without a password after a 10 second delay if I don't make a selection myself before that?

Comment: A boot manager isn't what your looking for.  You can select a default account that is about all you can do

Comment: Just one thing to keep in mind -- if your computer is ever stolen, you've now given them full and easy use of all the information on it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a boot manager to accomplish this. I'm not sure you can do this on a delay with a Scheduled Task either, but you can do it with a default account. It will log you in instantly, if you want to switch accounts, you can log off and switch.

To automatically log into a desired account on startup, follow these steps:

1. Click start, type `netplwiz` and run it as administrator.
2. **Click the name of the account that you wish to automatically log into.**

   [image]
3. Uncheck the box that says `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer`.
4. Enter the password for the account if one exists. If there is none, leave it blank. Then click Okay.

Windows will automatically log into the selected account using the provided password. If you want to undo this, simply run `netplwiz` again and re-check the box.

Comment: Thanks, Moses. I ran netplwiz as an Administrator to solve the problem. Nick C

Comment: @NIckC Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an autologin script. [There is another question that gives good detail on this.](https://superuser.com/questions/514265/set-user-for-auto-logon-on-windows-via-batch-script) In my experience auto logging of various types usually allow the `ctrl + alt + del` function to switch users (this would allow you back into your standard account). Also with an auto logging script you don't lose your ability to have a password set.