# Lock screen in Windows XP asks for password even though user login without password

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, lock-screen

On my home computer (that has MS Windows XP) I have accidentally pressed some key combination (what it might be?) that locked the computer.  The lock screen displays current user, and number of running applications, but *asks for a **password***.

This computer is set up to automatically login without password (I don't think that password is even set, and if it was I don't remember it). Can I go back to my *running* application (with unsaved data), or do I to come to terms with the loss of data?

Comment: log into the computer using the default Administrator account ( enable it if you need to ) and change the password to the user account you normally use.

Comment: You probably pressed `Win` + `L`.

Comment: Why not reboot....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just hitting [Enter]? Your password could be blank.  If not I don't believe there's a way to do this that doesn't involve forensically capturing data stored in RAM, which involves other tools and software.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried obvious passwords like  and "password", and exhausted your mental list of what you think it might be, then accept the loss and reboot.

Otherwise you're up against one of the main security features of the OS, which won't be easy to defeat (if it's even at all possible in the current state).

After you reboot and it automatically logs back in, check the auto-login registry entry to find out what the password is set to (it'll be in plain-text) -- for next time. :)

Comment: Where I can find this auto-login registry?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/514265/set-user-for-auto-logon-on-windows-via-batch-script, specifically this answer http://superuser.com/a/514293/23133 :)